# Calling a base class method in a template virtual class hierarchy

Tags: c++, templates, virtual

Let's say I have the following class hierarchy:

```
template< class T >
class TestBase {

public:

    virtual T const & do_foo() = 0;

};

template< class T >
class TestDerived : public virtual TestBase< T > {

public:

    virtual int do_bar() {
        return do_foo() + 1;
    }

};
```

GCC spits out the following:

```
error: there are no arguments to ‘do_foo’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘do_foo’ must be available [-fpermissive]
note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
```

Now, if I change this to derive from a TestBase instantiated from a known type (e.g. `class TestDerived : public virtual TestBase< int >`, this snippet compiles just fine so the problem apparently has to do with the base class type being unknown at compile time. But since I haven't instantiated objects of either class anywhere, I don't see why this should even matter.

Basically, how would I resolve the error without resorting to `-fpermissive`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `virtual T do_bar()` in `TestDerived`?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz - I don't think that's necessary, T could be any type such that `decltype(do_foo() + 1)` is an int (or can be implicitly converted to an int I think).

Comment: Oh, ok. It would trigger the instantiation certainly, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Non-dependent names (that is, names which do not depend on template arguments), are looked up when parsing the template, not when instantiating it. You need to make `do_foo` a dependent name. There are basically two ways to achieve this:

```
virtual int do_bar() {
    return this->do_foo() + 1;
}
```

or

```
template< class T >
class TestDerived : public virtual TestBase< T > {

public:
    using TestBase<T>::do_foo;

    virtual int do_bar() {
        return do_foo() + 1;
    }

};
```

Comment: There’s a third way: explicitly qualify the name instead of importing it via `using`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That would change semantics. If you use one of the ways I listed, the dynamic dispatch (virtual call) works normally. If you explicitly qualify, dynamic dispatch is bypassed.

Answer (score 0):

It will not win any awards for it's beauty, but this piece of code works as expected, without the compiler complaining.

```
virtual int do_bar() {
    return ((TestBase<T> *) this)->do_foo() + 1;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the cast. Using just `this->` works just as well.

Comment: Indeed, something else must've gone wrong when I tried that! Your answer is more complete; upvoted!

Comment: Thanks. For the record, I didn't downvote you (your answer isn't wrong per se).